# Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration

Tags: php, api, symfony

Hello I'm coding a symfony API for my hackathon event this is my first time using api in symfony but
it's still returning this annoying error i passed the true values but this error steal hitting me UPP
anyway m following this dude [tuto](https://www.kaherecode.com/tutorial/developper-une-api-rest-avec-symfony-et-api-platform-authentification) can someone help a brother out i lost my 8h in this and i could'n find a way  :'(((
requires
symfony 5
php 7
api platform

**this is my security.yml**

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: auto

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                username_path: email
                password_path: password
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api/
            stateless: true
            anonymous: true
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - lexik_jwt_authentication.jwt_token_authenticator
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/docs, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } # Allows accessing the Swagger UI
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/api/users, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

**this is my rootes.yml**

`authentication_token:     path: /api/login     methods: ['POST']`

**and this is my postman request**
[image]

i tried to re-generate my token file with
`$ openssl genrsa -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 4096`
`$ openssl rsa -pubout -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem`
and nothing happened.
A functional login root, that's all I want for Christmas
thanks

Comment: Did you add a passphrase to the key and configured it correctly in the `.env` file? Any funny characters? Try executing `bin/console lexik:jwt:check-config` to see if it gives you some pointers. Otherwise, and *just for the purpose of testing* I'd try generating the private key (and the corresponding public one) without passphrase with `-nodes` and removing the `JWT_PASSPHRASE` variable.

Comment: oh god i dont know to to thank you .. like you said Sir the problem was in the .env file cuz i did the input passphrase was not the same in the .env file thank thank thank youuuuuuuuuu

Answer (score 3):

Try generating SSL keys

```bash
php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair
```

src: [Lexik JWT docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html#generate-the-ssl-keys)